# Use s3 relative path in cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I would like to access supporting files of cloud formation from s3 using a relative path from where the template is

I felt like I need to use AWS::Include Transform and CodeUri together to achieve this but I am not sure how to do the same

Right now in cloudformation init am using

Below is the sample command

```
                        "1_Step1": {
                            "command": {
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "",
                                    [
                                        "powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command \"& { &'C:\\ step1.ps1'", -> ec2 internal path
                                        " bucketname-v/sub-version/dev/Artifacts” -> s3 folder full path 
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
```

and I need somthing like

```
                        "1_Step1": {
                            "command": {
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "",
                                    [
                                        "powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command \"& { &'C:\\ extractDevopsInstaller.ps1'", -> ec2 internal path
                                        " /Artifacts” -> s3 folder relative path ‘base of cloud formation template path from s3 ‘ 
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you're looking for the Fn::Split and Fn::Select intrinsic function.
e.g.:

```
Resources:
  Foobar:
    Type: Some::Resource::Type
    Properties:
      MyProperty: !Join
        - /
        - - C:\something
          - !Select
            - 1
            - !Split
              - /
              - some/awesome/path/to/my/template
```

or in JSON:

````
  "Resources": {
    "Foobar": {
      "Type": "Some::Resource::Type",
      "Properties": {
        "MyProperty": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "/",
            [
              "C:\something",
              {
                "Fn::Select": [
                  1,
                  {
                    "Fn::Split": [
                      "/",
                      "some/awesome/path/to/my/template"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````